# How can I achieve a scratchcard effect?

Tags: xamarin, monogame, cocossharp

I want to achieve a scratchcard effect like the one in the video below.
But it seems quite hard to me (I'm a newbie when it comes to 2D graphics), and I would greatly appreciate a little help, if you have some snippets that could set alpha of the pixels of a CCSprite, or at least somewhere to start looking.
I'm using cocossharp v1.7.1.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWfihxUm-Q4

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Clipper to substract a polygon (finger circle) from another polygon (your scratching area). Then use geometrynode to render the polygons. I'm currently doing exactly that in my game and it works fine.

Here is a blog post I wrote about (some of) it:
http://managedmonkey.blogspot.se/2015/08/using-textures-with-ccgeometrynode-in.html